# Testing tree circularity?

Tags: c, tree

I'm still not very good with data structures, but I have this homework assignment that wants me to test if a tree-like structure is circular or not. That is when, in some form or another, the left and right pointers at a node end up pointing back to an earlier node.

I've been trying to come up with a recursive function for hours now, but I just can't seem to get it. I don't really have much work to show for it too.
Can someone give me some ideas on how I can go about doing this?
The language we are using is C.

Thanks.

Comment: DFS or BFS and mark visited nodes.

Comment: By tree like, i mean that each node has a left and a right pointer to another node. Along with some other data fields.

Comment: Wouldn't the DFS/BFS with marking assume his "tree" contains some concept of "root" or "top" level node(s)?

Comment: Trick question! Tree's can't be circular. </jerk> The correct term for a "tree-like structure" that may be circular is a graph :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the best way to do this is with depth first search (DFS). Start with the root node, mark it as "visited", and start to follow the pointers. At each new node you reach, mark it as "visited". If you reach a dead-end, back up and try another path.

If you ever follow a pointer and reach a node you already marked as visited, then you've got a cycle.

How about doing it recursively:

```
struct node {
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    bool visited;
};

bool check_tree(struct node *cur)
{
    if (cur == NULL)
        return true;

    if (cur->visited)
        return false; // uh oh. We've been here...
    cur->visited = true;
    return check_tree(cur->left)
           && check_tree(cur->right);
 }

 if (check_tree(&root))
     printf("No self-references here.\n");
```

(warning: code may have bugs)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check out the [Topological Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort) algorithm.

You will notice in the pseudo code provided on the Wikipedia link, that, during the sort, you will become aware of any circular references.

```
L ← Empty list that will contain the sorted elements
S ← Set of all nodes with no incoming edges
while S is non-empty do
    remove a node n from S
    insert n into L
    for each node m with an edge e from n to m do
        remove edge e from the graph
        if m has no other incoming edges then
            insert m into S
if graph has edges then
    **output error message (graph has at least one cycle)**
else 
    output message (proposed topologically sorted order: L)
```

EDIT:

This answer was posted before the author indicated he basically has a double-linked-list structure. I posted it not because I think it would be the most efficient answer in all cases, but because given our lack of information about his graph (other than the description of it as a "tree") this answer should handle most any case.

Answer (score 1):

Floyd's 'Tortoise & Hare' algorithm should solve this very elegantly. Please see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection

It fits perfectly for lists, but could also be adapted to walk tree like graphs.

Comment: +1 - this is an elegant and easy solution. Adapting this to work with trees should be straightforward.

Comment: Veto this idea. This algorithm only works with lists because they are 1-dimensional. Graphs, in general, are not. So the way to "adapt" this algorithm is to turn it into BFS.... It is a nifty algorithm, tho

Comment: Both the "tortise" and "hare" would need their own independent "stacks" to keep track of whether they had gone left or right at any particular node, but provided that that requirement was met, I don't see any reason the tortise and hare algorithm wouldn't be just applicable for trees as for lists.

Comment: I think this is too general. My understanding is that the OP problem boils down to "node is referred more than one time", not "a sequence repetition".